# Error in training model for Faster-R-CNN implemented in Tensorflow and Caffe

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I am using the following github repository which implements a deep learning model called as Faster R-CNN in tensorflow, i want to :

https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF

Then, I run the command ( i'm want to run with CPU only ):

```
python ./tools/demo.py --model VGGnet_fast_rcnn_iter_70000.ckpt
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/demo.py", line 11, in <module>
    from networks.factory import get_network
  File "/home/brm17/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/networks/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .VGGnet_train import VGGnet_train
  File "/home/brm17/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/networks/VGGnet_train.py", line 2, in <module>
    from networks.network import Network
  File "/home/brm17/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/networks/network.py", line 3, in <module>
    import roi_pooling_layer.roi_pooling_op as roi_pool_op
  File "/home/brm17/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling_op.py", line 5, in <module>
    _roi_pooling_module = tf.load_op_library(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/brm17/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling.so: undefined symbol: _Z22ROIPoolBackwardLaucherPKffiiiiiiiS0_PfPKiRKN5Eigen9GpuDeviceE
```

what is the problem ,and how resolved this  ?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't follow the instructions in the repository.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remove tag `caffe` as it is not related.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install cuda (7.5 or 8.0) ([link to install cuda-8.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)).
Then, you need to go in your .bashrc file (which is located in your home) and add the following two lines:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin

Once the .bashrc file saved, run the following command:

source .bashrc

Do not forget to verify whether the two variables exists (simply by typing $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $PATH). If they don't, go to the paths in order to change the name of your folders (for instance I had to change "lib" by "lib64" in the first variable).

Then, it should work :-)